# Laravel именование экшенов

Tags: laravel

Вот такая ситуация:

```
<?php
class DictionaryController
{ 
    public function postAddWord($id_dictionary)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Какие варианты кроме заранее определение в route php:
`Route::post('/dictionary/add_word/{id_dictionary}'['uses'=>'D...@postAddWord']);`

Каким образом вы выходите из ситуации?

Comment: danilatorsu, вопрос абсолютно непоятен. Какие варианты *чего*?

Answer (score 1):

B `route.php`:

```
Route::Controller('dictionary', 'DictionaryController');
```

и обращение через `DictionaryController@postAddWord`